# Status comments and likes using OAuth

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, facebook-timeline, feed

I am just messing around with Facebook connect on my local machine. I created a very basic app using PHP where a user can type a comment, and it will be posted to the users Timeline/Wall, as well as the webpage.

I was wondering is there a tool where all comments/likes/feeds can be viewed on my webpage as well? Basically can that whole feed be viewed not on Facebook, but on my webpage?

Thanks,

Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the tool is called the Graph API.  When you get the correct access tokens you can easily pull comments, likes, feeds for the authenticated user.  See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: Sorry for the late comment.  Thanks for your answer :)